# i could not find org.codehaus.staxmate.dom package

Tags: java, xml, staxmate

I use netbeans 6.9 I want to use org.codehaus.staxmate.dom package but in does not exist. How can I add this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the jar files from http://staxmate.codehaus.org/
2. Open up Netbeans and add the jars that you fetched from 1

   - to add the jars, open up Tools -> Libraries and create a new class library. Finally, add this library to the project's "compile" tab under its libraries section
   - alternately you can simply right click the project -> properties and then add the jars under the "compile" tab under libraries

Generally, make it point to look for the jar file names here : http://www.jarfinder.com/

That will help you decide the jar file needed and where to download it from as well :)

Answer (score 1):

This package is not included in standard Java Runtime Environment. So,

- you either have to download corresponding jar manually, and specify as library in your project configuration
- or have to use some build manager in your project (for example, Maven) and specify dependency on corresponding package

Answer (score 1):

Download staxmate from:

[The Staxmate Web Site.](http://staxmate.codehaus.org/)